# How to overload a function or method on a generic type inside of a Vec?

Tags: rust

I need a function that operates on a vector that has a default implementation as well as specialized implementations for a few different types.

I can accomplish this:

```rust
trait Foo<T>
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Generic: {}", self.vectorize()[0]);
    }
    fn vectorize(&self) -> &Vec<T>;
}

impl Foo<f32> for Vec<f32> {
    fn vectorize(&self) -> &Vec<f32> {
        self
    }
}

impl Foo<f64> for Vec<f64> {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Specialized: {}", self[0]);
    }
    fn vectorize(&self) -> &Vec<f64> {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    vec![1.2_f32, 2.3].foo();
    vec![3.4_f64, 4.5].foo();
}
```

The strategy is to define a trait with a default implementation and then specialize it when required.  My problem is that we really need to know that the type is a `Vec` and therefore need this helper function `vectorize` to obtain the correct type.  This makes things a bit verbose and I'd like to do this better.

I don't really care if there's a trait or not; I just need a function that gets specialized on the different underlying `Vec` type and the only way I know how to do this is through the use of a trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to directly access an indexed value of the vector in your trait, which is a behavior defined by the [Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait of the std and is implemented by the `Vec` struct. So you just need to specify that the `Foo` trait require the `Index` trait to be implemented as well.

```
use std::ops::Index;

trait Foo<T>: Index<usize, Output = T>
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Generic: {}", self[0]);
    }
}

impl Foo<f32> for Vec<f32> {}

impl Foo<f64> for Vec<f64> {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Specialized: {}", self[0]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    vec![1.2_f32, 2.3].foo();
    vec![3.4_f64, 4.5].foo();
}
```